# Must specify Extended class type in child Class method return with TS 2.4

Tags: typescript, migration, parent-child, typescript2.4

I'm trying to migrate from TypeScript 2.3.2 to 2.4.2.

This code used to work in 2.3:

```
class Records {
  public save(): Records {
    return this;
  }
}

class User extends Records {
  public update(): User {
    return this.save();
  }
}

let myUser: User = new User();
let obj = myUser.update();
```

but now, it raises the following error on compilation:

> Error:(10, 5) TS2322: Type 'Records' is not assignable to type 'User'.
>    Property 'update' is missing in type 'Records'.

Of course, I can change update so that it returns "Records" like this:

```
  public update(): Records {
    return this.save();
  }
```

But I don't really get why I have to change this. It looks like a regression to me.
Anyone have an explanation or a better solution ? I find it makes my code harder to read.

Thanks a lot,

Julien

Comment: Although its almost a year since you had posted this question, I think my answer is the what you was looking for. What do you think? Hopefully some one benefits from it in the future ^_^ @JulienCo

Answer (score 1):

It's a typing issue. You are saying that `User.update` will return a `User`, but it actually returns the result of `Records.save`, which is of type `Records`. The `Records` type cannot be assigned to something expecting a `User` because `Records` does not have the `update` method.

In order to fix this, you must specify the return type of `update` to be `Records` (which it is currently returning) or you will need to modify `Records.save` to return a `User` (which will require changing the implementation of the method) -- your solution will depend on what you need from your program.

---

I think part of your confusion may come from the `extends` keyword -- it may seem like `User` and `Records` are kind of the same since `User` "`extends`" `Records`, but this is not the case. Read more about `extends` in the "Inheritance" section of this article: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html

---

In response to your comments (assuming you cannot change the implementation), a more accurate type for your `save` method would be a Union type of `User | Records` since it will return one or the other depending on the context in which it is called.

That would look like this:

```
public save(): Records | User {
  return this;
}
```

Read about Union types here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html

Comment: Thanks. update is still returning an User, though. But I understand your explanation: > let myUser: User = new User(); >
console.log(myUser.update().constructor.name); > User

Comment: Glad to help :) -- The reason update is returning a `User` is that it returns `this`, so whatever context it is in when it is called, it will return that context. So when you are calling `this.save` from the `User` class, you will get a `User`. As I said in my answer, you will need to either change the types or the implementation to get the typing to work correctly. It will not work as is.

Comment: I changed update def to `public update(): Records`. Thanks a lot.

Comment: That'll do it -- no problemo

Answer (score 0):

In OOP, the base class won't know what the new methods and new properties would be on the derived class, that's why complier complain you.

How about return 'this'? Is it possible for you?

```
class User extends Records {
   public update(): User {
      super.save();
      return this;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The ideal solution to your problem is to just remove the return type of `save()` method.

[Check it live](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Records%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20public%20save()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20this%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20User%20extends%20Records%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20public%20update()%3A%20User%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20this.save()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20myUser%3A%20User%20%3D%20new%20User()%3B%0D%0Alet%20obj%20%3D%20myUser.update()%3B)) (No Errors anymore)

Explanation: When the method becomes:

```
public save() { // With no explicit return type.
    return this;
}
```

This means that typescript "Type Inference" feature will infer the type to be `Records` or any child class of type `Records`.